# I've breached the ArcTec servers

Tags: cipher

Puzzle masters, I need your help. I've just breached ArcTec's secure servers and made off with a seemingly important file. However, it is encrypted and I can't break it.

To my knowledge, it is encrypted with ArcTec's proprietary "pairwise pulse" encryption. However, my program to break it failed; it spit an "out of phase" error. I don't actually understand their encryption; someone else made the program.

Knowing ArcTec's ego, the file likely contains the name "ArcTec" in many places. Hell, it's probably in the first line of the file!

**Can you figure out what the file actually says?**

> 22 38 15 33 27 12 22 15 34 17 10 28 29 20 23 12 34 12 12 39 23 12 19 18 13 14 17 39 29 21 22 12 36 13 12 19 20 22 32 32 11 21 29 28 22 13 32 18 29 23 37 17 17 17 39 29 23 12 19 18 13 14 19 28 15 39 24 15 22 19 22 30 29 11 27 15 39 26 38 15 37 21 29 20 25 32 29 24 15 22 19 21 27 14 16 10 24 17 18 15 39 27 15 39 24 15 22 19 24 33 10 21 32 15 39 23 30 28 28 22 15 17 39 29 24 35 19 22 38 16 36 30 25 32 22 13 19 23 10 22 37 21 25 20 25 37 39 29 29 29 21 22 12 34 17 18 15 39 28 15 32 17 39 29 21 26 16 36 30 23 15 17 39 29 24 15 22 19 22 30 29 11 27 15 39 26 38 15 37 21 29 23 28 13 16 39 20 29 24 23 12 10 24 19 24 15 23 12 10 24 19 24 18 19 28 16 13 19 28 19 12 13 10 24 17 18 15 39 24 18 19 23 28 13 12 32 19 24 15 22 16 39 28 16 14 19 28 13 29 24 15 22 19 23 30 28 28 22 15 17 39 22 22 11 29 17 14 12 19 28 16 13 19 24 23 12 10 24 12 13 19 25 36 16 34 32 13 11 29 20 25 32 29 24 12 12 35 29 20 22 23 30 25 34 10 24 22 19 24 15 22 17 13 19 24 13 10 27 15 37 15 34 29 20 25 32 29 24 15 22 17 13 19 20 22 23 30 25 32 32 12 29 26 32 15 34 10 28 29 20 24 37 18 27 14 17 12 11 29 25 20 23 32 19 24 27 13 32 15 39 24 15 22 16 39 24 15 22 19 26 19 19 12 13 19 25 20 25 32 29 20 24 20 27 15 31 24 19 28 16 13 19 24 13 18 18 19 11 27 39 27 15 39 20 22 22 27 14 17 18 15 39 24 15 22 15 19 29 18 11 21 22 11 21 29 27 25 38 11 18 22 12 24 22 19 28 13 29 24 10 22 34 17 12 31 29 24 18 19 23 17 13 30 28 29 28 16 13 19 28 11 15 37 39 21 12 19 21 17 18 28 29 25 32 12 12 29 24 18 19 23 27 15 32 29 20 29 21 10 25 19 24 18 19 24 20 27 15 39 20 25 39 20 22 23 30 25 34 10 24 22 19 28 13 32 13 19 24 15 22 19 26 38 15 37 21 29 20 25 32 29 22 23 17 13 32 19 24 15 22 16 39 28 16 14 17 39 21 12 19 25 32 12 12 29 24 18 19 21 24 16 12 25 19 24 15 22 17 13 19 20 24 37 18 27 14 17 12 11 29 20 25 32 29 28 22 10 23 15 39 24 18 19 22 38 16 15 34 12 13 10 22 34 19 24 15 22 16 37 39 29 29 29 21 27 14 16 10 24 17 18 15 39 23 12 19 18 13 14 17 39 29 20 23 12 34 12 12 39 27 11 29 22 38 22 10 23 17 15 34 29 28 16 14 19 24 15 22 19 24 33 10 21 32 15 39 23 30 28 28 22 15 19 21 28 19 24 15 22 15 19 22 30 25 39 24 32 14 27 15 39 20 29 26 37 15 37 15 34 29 28 19 12 13 10 24 17 18 15 39 23 28 13 19 23 30 28 26 10 24 38 22 19 26 37 15 32 13 10 28 21 29 21 17 14 15 27 15 39 24 15 22 19 23 30 28 28 22 15 17 39 25 28 11 12 13 32 13 19 24 15 22 13 12 19 21 12 13 12 19 27 15 32 27 13 37 12 26 10 28 21 29 23 12 11 27 12 27 15 34 29 27 15 39 24 15 22 19 23 30 28 28 22 15 17 39 21 15 27 18 22 19 26 38 11 24 19 25 20 23 32 19 28 22 13 24 19 21 17 18 28 27 15 34 28 25 19 24 15 22 19 22 30 29 11 27 15 39 26 38 15 37 21 29 25 20 23 32 19 23 12 13 26 11 22 12 29 24 18 19 28 22 10 23 32 19 24 15 22 17 13 19 23 28 13 14 13 12 11 21 29 27 15 39 24 15 22 19 23 30 28 28 22 15 19 23 12 14 20 23 12 28 22 11 21 29 28 13 29 24 15 22 19 29 13 17 12 32 19 29 13 18 19 18 11 22 12 29 28 13 19 24 15 22 19 24 15 23 12 10 24 11 29 26 30 22 22 17 39 21 28 19 26 32 19 20 25 32 29 26 35 19 26 32 15 39 25 20 23 32 19 24 32 12 15 39 21 22 15 34 19 27 15 39 24 18 19 23 28 18 28 28 11 19 24 15 23 18 16 14 25 29 28 15 39 24 15 28 11 22 19 24 15 23 12 10 24 11 29 20 25 32 29 22 38 22 10 23 19 24 15 22 16 39 28 16 14 19 24 35 19 23 28 13 12 32 17 39 28 13 32 13 19 24 15 22 19 28 20 21 24 19 24 15 23 12 12 19 26 38 15 34 15 21 29 21 12 19 25 20 23 32 19 22 15 34 20 24 22 12 29 27 15 39 26 30 25 35 19 21 27 27 13 16 37 11 25 22 11 29 20 25 32 29 24 30 24 14 18 22 11 29 20 24 20 27 15 31 24 19 24 15 22 19 26 38 15 37 21 27 39 24 15 26 11 29 23 20 23 19 21 12 19 25 20 23 32 19 25 38 14 19 26 30 22 22 19 26 36 12 35 29 25 22 10 22 21 10 25 19 27 15 39 24 15 22 19 28 15 34 28 17 15 34 29 28 19 12 13 10 24 17 18 15 39 26 30 27 15 38 25 19 22 26 12 19 24 18 19 24 15 22 19 26 38 15 37 21 29 29 15 25 11 27 12 30 28 29 20 25 32 29 26 32 15 34 10 28 29 29 13 18 11 12 11 21 27 39 29 29 29 20 23 12 34 12 12 39 23 12 11 28 16 13 12 32 11 27 39 29 20 24 19 29 13 12 11 22 15 34 19 21 12 19 25 20 23 32 19 28 13 32 13 19 23 27 13 32 19 25 26 15 32 23 12 12 29 24 13 18 18 19 11 29 27 15 39 24 15 22 19 23 30 28 28 22 15 19 20 25 32 29 22 30 25 39 22 30 28 28 29 27 15 39 26 38 13 12 19 20 21 29 25 32 12 12 22 12 27 39 24 15 27 11 29 24 23 10 25 34 11 29 26 11 29 20 29 26 30 21 21 27 13 32 19 25 36 16 34 32 13 11 29 20 22 23 30 25 34 10 24 22 17 39 20 21 29 28 28 15 34 29 20 21 29 21 12 19 22 38 15 34 17 15 36 12 19 24 18 19 23 12 12 32 17 13 32 19 23 26 15 32 27 15 34 29 23 23 18 16 39 25 20 19 21 12 19 22 30 25 39 22 38 15 34 17 15 36 12 19 24 15 22 19 20 24 14 10 22 37 29 27 15 32 22 13 27 15 37 14 12 18 25 17 39 29 29 29 21 12 19 25 20 23 32 19 22 11 24 10 24 38 27 11 25 22 12 29 20 29 24 30 21 22 19 28 13 29 28 19 12 13 10 24 17 18 15 31 29 27 15 39 24 15 22 19 23 30 28 28 22 15 17 39 28 16 13 19 24 30 21 22 19 25 20 21 29 28 20 23 14 22 19 21 24 18 12 37 29 17 18 22 11 29 28 13 29 21 12 10 29 18 15 31 29 20 26 36 36 15 37 14 17 18 15 39 20 25 32 29 28 14 15 22 13 19 21 26 19 19 18 27 12 11 27 39 27 15 39 20 22 22 27 14 17 18 15 39 28 16 13 19 24 30 21 22 19 23 22 10 24 16 13 12 11 29 28 20 23 14 22 19 28 19 12 15 39 21 29 10 22 32 11 29 29 13 12 13 32 15 34 17 15 34 29 24 15 22 19 26 38 15 37 21 29 23 23 18 16 39 22 38 13 15 32 13 17 15 34 29 20 25 32 29 24 13 10 29 19 17 15 34 29 24 13 18 18 19 11 29 21 15 27 12 35 29 25 20 29 19 12 15 31 29 24 18 19 24 32 19 20 29 23 20 23 38 13 12 12 29 24 10 22 34 17 12 39 28 13 29 24 15 22 17 13 11 27 39 29 29 29 21 15 27 18 22 19 21 12 19 22 28 19 25 38 14 19 22 38 15 34 13 18 18 29 26 36 12 35 29 28 13 29 24 15 22 19 23 30 28 28 22 15 19 21 12 19 22 28 19 25 20 23 32 19 21 28 16 32 19 21 26 19 19 18 25 19 22 35 20 27 15 31 29 23 16 15 35 37 15 34 29 24 15 23 18 16 14 25 29 24 15 22 19 20 23 12 10 21 29 21 12 19 22 28 19 22 38 15 34 13 18 18 27 39 26 38 11 24 19 28 13 29 28 16 13 19 23 28 13 11 10 23 12 29 24 30 21 22 11 29 20 23 12 19 26 38 15 37 29 23 28 13 14 17 13 27 12 30 24 17 18 15 31 29 21 12 19 25 20 23 32 19 22 30 29 14 16 13 12 12 29 20 25 32 29 22 38 15 33 32 13 14 12 12 27 39 29 29 29 21 12 19 25 20 23 32 19 20 29 26 30 26 28 13 19 24 12 12 35 29 20 22 23 30 25 34 10 24 22 19 28 13 32 13 19 24 15 22 19 26 38 15 37 21 27 39 24 15 22 15 19 26 11 22 19 21 21 18 13 12 21 27 39 21 12 19 24 33 18 16 14 25 24 19 24 26 15 31 27 39 21 15 27 18 22 19 24 15 22 15 19 22 30 25 39 21 28 16 32 15 28 11 19 26 38 13 32 19 23 20 21 24 19 22 15 38 16 14 25 29 24 18 19 22 28 12 24 22 19 24 36 18 28 22 14 11 29 24 15 22 15 19 22 30 25 39 25 38 14 19 22 28 12 24 22 19 28 16 13 19 22 11 39 12 13 17 16 32 15 34 10 28 29 28 20 21 22 13 19 21 12 10 29 18 15 31 27 39 28 16 13 19 21 24 10 25 32 20 23 12 29 24 38 12 25 19 20 23 16 38 13 19 27 11 29 28 13 29 28 27 14 14 18 22 19 26 11 22 19 24 36 14 19 25 22 10 23 35 19 29 18 11 12 13 12 12 29 20 23 16 38 13 19 21 22 12 16 31 29 24 18 19 29 13 18 13 37 12 22 19 22 13 23 22 12 34 17 13 32 19 29 13 18 14 12 12 34 17 18 15 37 39 29 29 29 21 22 12 34 17 18 15 39 24 11 18 17 39 29 26 38 15 37 29 24 13 10 27 15 37 15 34 27 39 29 22 30 29 11 27 15 39 26 38 15 37 21 29 20 23 12 19 24 13 10 27 15 32 12 29 24 18 19 29 12 13 13 22 12 34 17 18 15 39 27 15 39 29 15 25 11 27 12 30 28 29 22 38 16 34 30 24 17 39 24 15 22 17 13 19 21 21 18 13 12 21 26 30 25 31 25 27 19 19 27 11 29 24 32 15 18 15 32 29 22 38 16 39 10 23 12 17 39 24 15 22 15 19 21 24 13 17 17 22 19 24 15 23 18 16 14 25 29 26 38 11 24 19 20 23 16 38 13 19 20 25 32 29 24 10 27 22 19 28 16 14 19 20 29 26 30 25 39 27 15 39 28 15 32 19 21 24 13 17 17 22 17 39 24 15 22 17 13 19 23 12 10 22 34 17 18 15 39 24 17 16 32 19 27 11 29 23 20 21 24 19 22 15 38 16 14 25 29 24 18 19 22 28 12 24 22 19 24 26 15 33 27 13 12 17 39 25 28 11 12 13 32 13 19 24 15 27 11 29 26 30 25 19 26 26 11 24 19 24 32 19 22 30 26 11 22 12 29 24 35 19 24 15 22 17 13 19 29 13 12 12 38 14 25 37 14 17 18 15 37 39 29 24 15 22 15 19 23 16 15 39 20 24 19 24 23 12 10 24 19 21 29 12 12 12 29 28 13 32 13 19 20 28 26 38 11 24 19 20 25 35 19 24 12 13 13 10 27 15 39 28 13 19 28 13 32 13 19 26 38 11 24 19 28 14 31 24 10 22 38 22 11 27 39 24 15 22 15 19 20 23 12 19 20 28 21 28 19 24 13 10 27 15 32 12 29 27 15 39 20 29 21 17 12 22 19 20 23 13 10 25 19 28 13 29 23 27 12 18 22 21 29 27 15 32 38 26 12 27 15 34 29 24 10 22 34 17 12 31 29 20 25 32 29 21 24 13 10 24 12 14 25 17 39 24 15 22 15 19 25 20 23 32 19 22 22 16 38 15 31 24 13 10 24 12 12 29 24 15 22 19 20 24 37 18 27 14 15 19 24 18 19 26 11 22 19 20 25 35 19 28 13 29 28 16 13 19 21 12 10 29 18 15 31 29 28 13 19 22 10 16 17 19 16 32 15 34 19 24 15 22 15 19 25 20 29 19 12 15 39 24 18 19 24 10 27 22 19 23 23 18 16 39 26 11 27 39 29 29 29 26 32 15 34 10 28 29 29 18 11 12 13 11 27 39 29 27 15 39 20 22 22 27 14 17 18 15 39 24 18 19 24 15 22 17 13 19 22 11 34 13 12 16 32 19 29 15 25 11 27 12 30 28 29 24 13 10 27 15 37 15 34 29 20 25 32 29 27 15 31 24 13 16 12 34 17 18 15 39 24 15 22 19 22 30 29 11 27 15 39 26 38 15 37 21 29 20 28 21 28 19 29 18 11 21 22 11 21 29 29 18 11 12 13 13 26 18 29 26 32 15 34 10 28 29 20 24 37 18 27 14 17 12 11 29 24 15 20 24 19 23 26 13 14 15 22 13 19 24 17 18 24 19 24 15 22 19 28 12 22 21 29 27 15 39 24 15 22 17 13 19 23 20 23 38 13 17 39 29 29 29 24 15 22 15 19 22 28 19 25 38 14 19 25 32 12 12 29 23 28 18 12 29 28 13 19 21 10 24 12 13 17 39 24 15 22 15 19 24 30 23 12 18 25 19 25 32 12 12 29 21 28 22 12 19 17 39 22 35 28 17 27 15 34 29 24 15 22 17 13 19 23 12 11 28 16 13 12 32 11 29 21 17 18 28 29 25 38 14 19 21 24 18 19 19 24 15 22 16 37 39 24 15 22 15 19 22 28 19 25 38 14 19 25 32 12 12 29 24 15 22 16 37 39 27 15 39 20 22 22 27 14 17 18 15 39 24 15 22 15 19 25 20 23 32 19 22 22 16 38 15 31 24 13 10 24 12 12 29 20 25 39 20 23 23 27 15 37 14 15 19 23 28 13 19 25 22 10 24 19 20 25 32 29 22 38 18 22 27 39 24 15 22 15 19 22 28 19 25 38 14 19 21 22 12 16 39 24 18 19 24 32 19 20 23 23 22 12 34 12 12 29 24 35 19 22 13 32 15 39 22 11 34 13 12 16 32 19 24 12 16 39 12 13 10 24 16 13 12 11 27 39 29 29 29 24 15 22 17 13 19 25 30 24 16 13 10 28 28 25 19 21 25 20 23 19 19 23 12 10 22 34 17 18 15 39 24 17 16 32 19 27 11 29 22 15 35 20 25 32 32 12 29 23 26 13 14 15 22 13 19 24 35 19 29 13 12 12 38 14 25 37 14 17 18 15 37 39 24 15 22 15 19 25 20 23 32 19 21 25 28 11 15 39 28 15 39 21 22 13 32 13 10 28 29 28 12 32 30 21 27 18 15 31 29 24 15 22 19 20 24 37 18 27 14 15 19 24 18 19 22 22 14 12 12 34 19 22 13 32 15 34 11 29 21 25 28 13 14 18 25 19 24 32 13 28 13 12 19 24 15 22 15 19 25 20 29 19 12 15 37 39 24 15 22 15 19 20 28 21 28 19 25 20 23 32 19 24 12 18 22 17 27 15 32 14 17 12 39 20 24 37 18 27 14 17 12 11 29 21 15 27 12 35 29 24 15 22 15 19 26 11 22 19 24 18 19 24 23 12 10 24 19 22 13 23 22 12 34 19 27 15 39 24 30 24 14 18 22 19 24 18 19 22 27 11 29 18 20 22 32 19 24 13 18 18 19 11 29 20 25 32 29 22 33 12 10 24 12 19 22 27 11 24 13 10 22 34 17 18 15 31 27 39 29 29 29 24 15 22 15 19 20 28 21 28 19 25 22 10 28 29 23 23 18 16 39 21 18 16 15 32 21 29 26 36 12 35 29 23 20 21 24 12 13 19 24 15 20 25 39 22 11 39 12 12 34 12 12 27 39 21 15 27 18 22 19 25 38 14 19 23 20 21 24 19 22 15 38 16 14 25 29 24 18 19 24 16 13 15 39 24 15 22 19 24 17 12 22 19 28 13 29 28 15 32 19 24 30 24 14 18 22 19 24 15 27 11 29 25 22 10 28 27 15 34 29 29 13 12 13 32 15 34 11 29 26 11 29 23 23 18 16 39 21 12 10 23 17 15 34 29 24 15 22 16 39 22 28 11 15 39 23 23 18 16 39 24 30 24 14 18 22 19 24 18 19 24 30 24 14 18 22 17 39 20 25 35 14 15 27 15 34 29 28 22 11 21 29 24 15 20 25 39 22 30 29 14 16 13 12 12 29 28 13 19 22 22 10 22 29 27 11 29 25 38 14 15 27 15 34 29 20 24 20 27 15 31 24 19 24 15 22 16 37 39 29 29 29 26 38 15 37 29 23 12 11 28 16 13 12 32 11 27 39 29 21 12 19 27 25 38 11 19 24 15 22 13 12 19 20 23 12 19 20 24 19 28 22 10 21 24 19 21 27 11 34 15 19 26 38 15 37 21 27 39 25 28 11 12 13 32 13 19 24 15 22 13 12 19 22 38 16 18 22 29 24 32 19 20 21 29 26 30 25 35 19 20 21 29 24 11 18 19 25 26 15 32 23 12 12 29 28 13 29 24 15 22 16 37 39 22 11 39 12 13 17 12 15 32 32 19 25 20 21 29 21 25 28 11 15 39 24 15 20 24 19 28 15 32 19 26 38 15 37 29 27 11 29 20 29 24 15 23 12 10 24 19 24 18 19 20 29 22 22 12 32 15 34 19 25 36 16 34 32 13 19 28 13 29 28 16 13 19 24 13 18 18 19 11 29 21 28 19 22 30 26 14 17 18 15 39 27 11 29 21 10 23 13 10 25 34 12 12 27 39 29 29 29 24 15 22 19 26 38 15 37 21 29 26 30 27 15 39 24 30 21 22 19 28 13 29 28 19 12 13 10 24 17 18 15 31 29 27 11 29 24 15 22 17 13 19 23 28 13 14 13 12 11 21 29 21 15 27 12 35 29 21 12 19 25 20 23 32 19 25 12 14 19 24 18 19 24 33 12 10 22 35 27 39 21 12 19 27 25 38 11 19 24 15 22 15 19 25 20 23 32 19 28 20 23 14 22 19 21 24 18 12 37 29 17 18 22 11 29 28 13 29 21 26 19 19 18 27 12 11 29 21 17 14 15 27 15 39 27 15 32 38 26 12 27 15 34 29 21 12 10 29 18 15 31 27 39 27 15 39 20 22 22 27 14 17 18 15 39 24 18 19 24 15 22 17 13 19 23 28 13 14 13 12 11 21 29 24 15 22 15 19 20 28 21 28 19 22 38 15 34 13 18 18 29 21 26 30 28 28 22 13 19 23 28 13 14 17 13 27 12 30 24 17 18 15 31 29 24 15 23 18 16 14 25 28 16 14 19 24 15 22 19 23 30 28 28 22 15 17 39 21 29 12 12 37 13 27 12 30 28 28 25 19 21 10 24 12 35 29 24 18 11 12 13 11 27 39 24 15 22 11 22 19 24 18 11 12 13 11 29 26 11 26 10 28 28 25 19 25 20 23 32 19 24 11 18 19 24 18 19 23 28 16 13 19 26 38 15 37 21 29 20 25 32 29 25 38 14 19 26 30 25 35 19 21 26 19 19 18 27 12 11 27 39 24 15 22 15 19 25 20 23 32 19 21 28 16 32 19 23 28 13 16 39 28 13 29 23 28 20 24 29 24 30 21 22 12 29 22 38 16 36 36 15 37 12 30 24 17 18 15 31 29 23 12 18 20 25 19 24 36 14 19 21 12 19 22 28 19 25 38 14 19 25 20 23 32 19 20 22 32 32 11 21 29 24 18 19 24 15 22 19 22 38 12 22 11 29 24 18 19 26 15 32 22 13 11 24 10 25 32 29 24 15 22 11 22 19 22 38 16 36 36 15 37 12 30 24 17 18 15 31 27 39 29 29 29 24 15 22 19 26 38 15 37 21 29 25 20 23 32 19 25 38 14 19 24 36 17 18 24 19 21 26 19 19 18 25 19 22 35 20 27 15 31 29 24 15 23 18 16 14 25 29 24 15 22 19 23 30 28 28 22 15 17 39 25 28 11 12 13 32 13 19 22 26 12 19 24 18 19 24 15 22 17 13 19 20 24 37 18 27 14 17 12 11 29 24 15 22 15 19 22 28 19 25 38 14 19 23 12 10 28 28 25 19 25 32 12 12 29 24 18 17 39 21 21 18 13 12 21 29 22 28 19 25 38 14 19 25 32 12 12 29 23 12 18 28 10 22 27 15 34 29 20 25 32 29 26 38 15 37 21 29 22 28 19 25 38 14 19 25 32 12 12 29 23 28 18 12 27 39 29 29 29 21 22 12 34 17 18 15 39 24 15 23 12 12 17 39 29 24 28 17 15 34 29 23 28 13 11 10 23 12 27 39 29 24 15 22 19 29 18 20 25 39 24 28 17 15 34 29 23 28 11 10 23 12 29 27 11 29 20 16 17 14 12 19 21 27 16 39 18 22 17 39 21 12 19 24 36 13 15 39 24 15 22 16 39 28 16 14 19 24 18 19 24 15 22 19 28 20 21 24 17 39 21 12 19 28 16 14 15 36 16 34 32 13 19 24 15 22 16 37 39 22 13 32 15 39 27 13 29 24 15 22 15 19 27 27 18 28 29 24 11 18 19 28 13 19 24 15 23 12 12 19 28 13 29 26 11 29 23 28 13 19 22 13 32 13 15 19 26 38 15 37 29 21 12 19 27 27 18 28 29 21 12 19 22 30 25 39 24 22 14 19 25 32 11 19 24 13 18 18 19 11 29 20 25 32 29 24 15 22 15 19 22 30 25 39 25 38 14 17 39 27 13 29 21 12 19 26 26 11 24 19 27 22 12 19 19 24 15 22 19 24 30 24 14 18 22 19 24 28 17 15 34 29 24 15 22 15 19 21 17 18 28 29 22 17 14 15 22 13 19 21 26 13 13 12 15 32 22 13 19 28 13 19 20 28 28 29 28 13 29 24 15 22 16 39 21 17 18 28 29 22 27 12 17 39 29 29 29 20 24 14 13 17 14 17 18 15 39 23 20 23 38 13 11 29 24 15 22 19 21 27 12 22 19 21 17 14 15 29 24 15 22 19 26 38 11 24 19 23 12 11 28 16 13 12 32 11 29 20 25 32 29 27 15 39 24 15 27 11 29 24 30 24 14 18 22 19 26 30 25 39 18 11 12 13 19 27 11 29 24 15 22 19 22 33 17 14 17 12 30 28 29 23 12 11 28 16 13 12 32 17 39 20 21 29 28 28 15 34 29 20 21 29 24 15 22 19 25 27 14 25 22 13 19 26 19 11 29 22 38 15 34 17 15 36 12 19 24 18 19 21 22 15 32 29 24 15 22 19 25 32 12 12 22 12 29 26 32 15 39 20 25 32 29 21 26 19 19 18 27 12 11 29 28 16 13 19 23 37 12 34 18 13 15 19 27 11 29 24 26 10 23 10 25 34 12 12 12 27 39 27 14 19 27 11 29 28 15 38 25 19 20 29 26 30 24 14 12 13 19 28 13 29 24 17 16 32 17 39 29 29 29 22 15 32 29 28 13 29 23 27 18 22 17 36

---

Massive Hint:

> "92" is a space.

Comment: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Comment: Please see [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do)

Comment: @Deusovi Jinx :-)

Comment: I like the compelling story though. Mean-spirited jokes aside, this looks like AES to me.

Comment: My apologies, I was going to do exactly what that says not to. I've added a couple of clues.

Comment: There is a reason I didn't add the story tag.

Comment: Pairs are key but, if a singlet is a two digit number and a pair is a set of two digit numbers, there are an odd number of pairs. Also, every two digit number is between 10 and 39, inclusive.

Comment: @EngineerToast I don't want to give too much away, but when I say "pair" I mean two digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last hint ...

> ... says that 92 is a space. This leads to the assumption that the cipher is a substitution cipher. However, there is no 92 in the encoded text.

But if we ...

> ... remove the first and last digits and rearrange the pairs so that a real pair flanks the spaces in the encoded text, i.e. so that the message now starts with 23 81 53 32, we get pairs whose first digit is 0 through 9 and whose second digit is 1 through 3.
>
>  We know from the hints that 92 is a space. The most frequent pairs are 92 (965 occurrences), 21 (552) and 41 (418), so 21 is probably an E. We can now find occurrences of THE to determine that 41 is T and 52 is H.
>
>  We also know from the hints that the word ArcTec occurs and finding a six letter word on the pattern 123TE3 yields that A is 02, R is 31 and 23 is C. It also looks as if 73 was a terminating punctuation, most likely a full stop. We now have enough letters to decode more words.

The final decoding table looks like this:

> `.    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9`
>
>  `1    Q  W  E  R  T  Y  U  I  O  P`
>  `2    A  S  D  F  G  H  J  K  L  _`
>  `3    Z  X  C  V  B  N  M  .`
>
>  where the top row is the tens digit, the left column the ones digit. This layout looks familiar, of course: It is an English keyboard and the first digit determines the columns, the second digit the row. (Note: There is no Z in the message.)
>
>  (I've seen that pattern only after decoding. Spotting it earlier may have been helpful, but the Golden-Bug-style decoding is easy enough to do by hand.)

Oh, and the contents of the file? Here goes:

> **confidential arctec report.**
>  secure access level viii.
>  report on the capsin monks and the situation in the braxen valley.
>  by commander rackshan.
>
>  **section one.**
>  **summary.**
>  the capsin monks form a great threat to our operation to force them out of the valley. despite our greater numbers and tech advantage their training and their advanced mental abilities have given them the upper hand against our troops. in addition they possess knowledge of tactics to rival our own. we will need to find a way to gain an advantage over the monks and drive them out. we need to study their abilities and learn to counteract them.
>
>  **situation report.**
>  arctec is clearing out the braxen valley so they can begin a mining operation for valuable minerals within the valley. however there were individuals residing in the valley. while most have left willingly the capsin monks have refused to leave their fortress in the valley regardless of the price proposed or the threats made. so me and my men have been sent in to follow through on those threats and clear them out by force. over the last three months we have engaged in many skirmishes and battles against the monks. thus far we have not made much headway in the ongoing operation mainly due to the monks physical and mental prowess.
>
>  **arctec resources.**
>  at present we have over five hundred troops in the valley and can call in more as needed. this grants us a massive numbers advantage. as long as we continue to receive funding from hq we can continue the attack indefinitely.
>
>  we have established a base of operations in the valley. our base has large stockpiles of weapons ammunition and other supplies. in addition our base features large open spaces preventing the monks from cornering and trapping troops which happens to be a favored tactic of theirs.
>
>  while we do not control much of the valley we do have some supply chains running through the areas we do control. most of our forward bases are monk fortifications we have captured and converted.
>
>  we have a major tech advantage over the monks. they use swords. we brought guns. while they can somehow move fast enough to dodge bullets they can not dodge our experimental laser weapons. our standard body armor is of little use but heavy powered armor seems to provide effective protection.
>
>  **section two.**
>  **monk training.**
>  capsin monks are trained to perfection in physical combat. their swordsmanship is beyond compare. they strike through most armor and take out a man in one strike. their reaction time is fast enough to dodge gunfire. however this may just be caused by their precognition.
>  they run at great speed over almost any terrain or over most obstacles. they are also trained in a wide array of fields including tactics and strategy. they have demonstrated the ability to use any of our weapons or equipment they happen to take from us.
>
>  **mental powers.**
>  in addition to their extreme physical training and instruction the capsin monks also possess powerful mental abilities that further tilt the odds in their favor.
>
>  they do not need food or water. they barely need sleep. choking their resources will not stop them. they do not need them. in addition they have demonstrated an affinity for heat and cold. they do not seem to be affected by even extreme temperatures.
>
>  their naturally sharp reaction time is enhanced further by precognition. they have shown on several occasions the ability to detect events shortly before they happen. they also have telekinetic abilities which they use to great effect in battle to displace troops and create distractions.
>
>  they also heal from wounds much faster than expected. while not fast enough to turn the tide of one battle this healing prevents us from wearing them down from battle to battle. anything less than captured or dead is nothing against them.
>
>  **monk resources.**
>  we know there are at least sixty monks. however there could be as many as two hundred of them. experience has shown that one monk is a threat to a decent number of our troops so caution is warranted.
>
>  the monks main base of operations is their fortress which we have yet to breach. we know they have large stockpiles of supplies within including weapons. in addition to their fortress they also control smaller fortifications throughout the valley. specifically watch towers. these towers usually have two to four monks and not many supplies. they have some form of flag based communications relay but we do not have access to the codes to understand these communications.
>
>  the monks have not built supply chains through the valley. however due to their abilities they do not really need to. swords do not need reloading and monks do not need food.
>
>  **section three.**
>  **going forward.**
>  the plan going foward is quite simple. we burn them out to the last. we outnumber them. even if they kill two or three of us for every monk we kill we can get new troops and they can not. if we just keep the battle going they will either surrender or all of them will die.
>
>  attrition favors the side with the most resources and in this battle manpower is the critical resource. as long as the higher ups continue to send the needed men and supplies our victory is guaranteed. it is only a matter of time.
>
>  end of file.

Comment: You've got it exactly.